# Mount internal drive to all users

Tags: mount, fstab

I have an internal 8tb harddrive which I want it to be mounted to all users on my machine some of the users are local and some are ldap users.

I've created a folder called 8tb in `/media/8tb`

Then I added the below to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda /media/8tb ext4 user,defaults 0 1
```

Now I wonder how to make this drive mounted to all users?